# Finding the intersection of two "half" hyperbolas with equations of the form $\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}-\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}=C$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I have two hyperbola equations that need to find an interaction,
I tried to use the GeoGebra to draw the graph, but I cannot implement this using C++ as I am not able to convert the two equations like
$x = \text{??}$ or $y = \text{??}$.

Is there any software or anyway I can make these two equations to be the format like: $x = \text{??}$ and $y = \text{??}$ ?
For your convenience, I will paste the equation here:

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}-\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}=C_1 \\[6pt]
\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}-\sqrt{(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2}=C_2
\end{align}$$

[image]

Thank you so much for your help, appreciated

Comment: Hence those hyperbolae have a focus in common, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is an analytical solution to your problem (it is almost half a mile long).

Instead, take the first equation and square it. This gives a quadratic equation in $y(x)$ (two roots). Plug in the second equation, repeat squaring to have a single equation in $x$ and ... have fun !

Comment: Thanks mate, I have tried but the result is super long and does not seems to have an end, do you have any software or website that you have in your mind that can do this kind of things? Really appreciated